# CSS3 Grid - Equal spacing between text in columns while keeping the first & last aligned to opposite edges

Tags: css, css-grid

The problem I experience is best summarized with a picture and an explanation.
I am using CSS3 Grid and I have 4 columns in the same row, all containing a string of 4 digits as shown below.

The Problem is that I can't figure out  a way to make sure the text of the first- and last column of the row is aligned to the edges while still keeping equal spacing between the content of all 4 columns:

[image: Picture]

I have tried centering the text, but this results in the card number not being aligned with the edges of the grid.

**Relevant HTML (Angular)**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let section of _CardNumberSections">
  <div class="card-number-section">
    {{ section }}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

**Relevant CSS**

```
.credit-card{
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    -ms-grid-rows: auto 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 5px;
    width: 326px;
    //height:204px;
    padding:27px 27px 17px 27px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 24px 0px rgba(0,0,0, 0.07);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;

.card-number-section{
    -ms-grid-row: 3;
    grid-row:3;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: $family-open-sans;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #4a4a4a;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create empty columns to use as separators:

```css
.credit-card {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto 1fr auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: "a . b . c . d";
  -ms-grid-rows: auto 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  width: 326px;
  //height:204px;
  padding: 27px 27px 17px 27px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

.card-number-section {
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-area: a;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: $family-open-sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: wheat;
}

.card-number-section:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: b;
}

.card-number-section:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: c;
}

.card-number-section:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: d;
}
```

```html
<div class="credit-card">
  <div class="card-number-section">1111</div>
  <div class="card-number-section">2222</div>
  <div class="card-number-section">3333</div>
  <div class="card-number-section">4444</div>
</div>
```

alternative snippet using columns:

```css
.credit-card {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto 1fr auto 1fr auto;
  -ms-grid-rows: auto 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  width: 326px;
  //height:204px;
  padding: 27px 27px 17px 27px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

.card-number-section {
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 1;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: $family-open-sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: wheat;
}

.card-number-section:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 3;
}

.card-number-section:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 5;
}

.card-number-section:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 7;
}
```

```html
<div class="credit-card">
  <div class="card-number-section">1111</div>
  <div class="card-number-section">2222</div>
  <div class="card-number-section">3333</div>
  <div class="card-number-section">4444</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure why I didn't think of this, it is such a simple solution and also makes it easier for me to make the dashes in between.

However grid areas aren't supported in older versions of IE as i recall. So i suppose i would have to change my actual html structure in order to support those?

Comment: I used areas because it is easier to see the structure using them. You can get the same results using columns (added snippet)

Answer (score 2):

You can align them horizontally (inline axis) with [justify-self](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-justify-self).
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LqbXVm)

```css
.credit-card{
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    -ms-grid-rows: auto 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 5px;
    width: 326px;
    padding:27px 27px 17px 27px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: lightsalmon;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 24px 0px rgba(0,0,0, 0.07);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card-number-section{
    -ms-grid-row: 3;
    grid-row:3;
  justify-self: center; /* 2 and 3 */
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: $family-open-sans;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #4a4a4a;
}

.card-number-section:first-child {
  justify-self: start; /* 1 */
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.card-number-section:last-child {
  justify-self: end; /* 4 */
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="credit-card">
  <div class="card-number-section">Left</div>
  <div class="card-number-section">Center</div>
  <div class="card-number-section">Center</div>
  <div class="card-number-section">Right</div>
</div>
```